# Handling Async With Specflow for Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, tdd, bdd, specflow

The Silverlight Unit test Framework defines a process for dealing with Async calls (derive test class from Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing.SilverlightTest, add Asynchronous attribute, use EnqueueXXX methods.)  Considering the separation that SpecFlow presents between the test class and the steps:

- Can these tools be brought to bear to wait on Silverlight method calls within the test that behave asynchronously (such as making web service calls)?
- If they cannot, what is the guidance for handling this behavior in SpecFlow test files? (Perhaps use an AutoResetEvent that gets tripped in an event handler and wait on it?)

Answer (score 3):

Using an AutoResetEvent won't work because the WaitOne call will block the UI thread. Silverlight makes use of the UI thread even when making async calls to a data services (see this post - [Thead is blocked using WebClient and ManualResetEvent](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/215676/511377.aspx)) so the WaitOne will actually stop the service from being called.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is probably to late but here goes.

For silverlight async calls you can use the Specflow AsyncContext api

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Testing-Silverlight-Asynchronous-Code

I blogged about this when it was being developed here

http://rburnham.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/testing-silverlight-asynchronous-code-with-specflow/

It helps to explain the concept.

Answer (score 1):

I guess everyone who has looked at and upvoted this question has been waiting for someone to have an awesome, elegant answer, but it does not look that that will happen here.  To help others who need a usable answer now...

What I have done with other unit-testing situations is use an AutoResetEvent like you have mentioned in the question:

```
AutoResetEvent MyAutoReset = new AutoResetEvent();
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
   var MyItem.GetItem(x => 
      {
         // Return handler
         MyAutoReset.Set();
      });
   MyAutoReset.WaitOne(5000, false));
}
```

Obviously there are a few things to consider with this approach, but it gets the idea across.

Comment: Thanks for the update Jason. Obviously, it has been a while since this was initially posted. I'll be happy to mark it as an answer when I can get some time to apply this code to a SpecFlow-originated test. Also, I am wondering if the new Async CTP will bring anything to bear on the problem.